# How to initialize mean and variance of Pytorch BatchNorm2d?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I’m transforming a TensorFlow model to Pytorch. And I’d like to initialize the mean and variance of BatchNorm2d using TensorFlow model.
I’m doing it in this way:

```
bn.running_mean = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(TF_param))
```

And I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: the derivative for 'running_mean' is not implemented
```

But is works for `bn.weight` and `bn.bias`. Is there any way to initialize the mean and variance using my pre-trained Tensorflow model? Is there anything like `moving_mean_initializer` and `moving_variance_initializer` in Pytorch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The running mean and variance of a batch norm layer are not `nn.Parameters`, but rather a [*buffer*](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer) of the layer.

I think you can simply assign a `torch.tensor`, no need to wrap a `nn.Parameter` around it.

Comment: WoW! It worked! Thank you! By the way, if I freeze bn parameters (stop bn from updating), the `running_mean` and `running_var` will not change. The running_mean and running_var will be saved in model directly. Am I right? Sorry for bad English expression.

Comment: @han.liu batch norm running statistics are updated on forward pass not by the optimizer. To freeze the running statistics during training set the momentum of each batch norm layer to zero. Alternatively if the model is in eval mode the running statistics will not be updated.